# How to avoid random console messages to capture in python pexpect buffer

Tags: python

I am having a very specific problem related to `Pexpect`. I am using `python 3.6.5` and  using `pexpect` to telnet to my remote servers.

Problem is that when I send commands on terminal servers, sometimes because of development team errors, some random console messages pops up inbetween command response though they are not actually part of the response which result in capturing these console messages in the buffer too.

Is there a way I can avoid these messages from the buffer such that output buffer will have only command output or Can i filter these console messages from the buffer . (Filtering I am not sure because there may be different messages that pops up randomly)

Is there any pythogenic way to handle it or should I have to live with it

Adding more information---- I am `connecting to terminal via serial connection via terminal server`

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the kernel messages from being printed to console using `sudo dmesg --console-off` (or `sudo dmesg -D`) cmd. Run it on each server you connect to via pexpect

```
$ sudo dmesg -h | grep console
 -D, --console-off           disable printing messages to console
 -E, --console-on            enable printing messages to console
 -n, --console-level <level> set level of messages printed to console
```

Comment: I liked the idea but whatever are printing on console are not error messages. Its like somestring is coming randomly say after 5 minutes on the terminal. Example: "Hey I am alive". When my script executes, it may happen that when I sent the command, this message will pop up between command and end Prompt which will result in pexpect buffer having this string. There can be n number of such strings so that I cannot filter them out based on pattern.

Comment: Whether this will turn off all the message prints? After disabling the console messages, If i send a command on the terminal, will I get command output